# Created form not submitting after calling .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to create a form and call the submit on the fly like the following:
(Chrome working, not on Firefox)

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.name="openGame";
form.method = "post";
form.action="/public/games";
var lat = document.createElement("input");
lat.name="latitude";
lat.value=$("#city[name=latitude]").val() || " ";
lat.type="hidden";
form.appendChild(lat);
var lng = document.createElement("input");
lng.name="longitude";
lng.value=$("#city[name=longitude]").val() || " ";
lng.type="hidden";
form.appendChild(lng);
var address = document.createElement("input");
address.name="city";
address.value=$("#city[name=city]").val() || " " ;
address.type="hidden";
form.appendChild(address);
var game = document.createElement("input");
game.name="game";
game.value=id;
game.type="hidden";
form.appendChild(game);
form.submit();
```

but the form is actually not submitting. No errors, no outputs in the console

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your form was never appended to the DOM.

You can't submit a form that's not rendered in Firefox.

If you don't want to show it, append it to the DOM with `display: none`.

Another approach would be to build an XMLHttpRequest manually, or $.post in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution (thanks to Dan M.) is to append the form to the DOM before to submit it.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.style = {
        display : "none"
    };
    form.name="openGame";
    form.method = "post";
    form.action="/public/games";
    var lat = document.createElement("input");
    lat.name="latitude";
    lat.value=$("#citta[name=latitude]").val() || " ";
    lat.type="hidden";
    form.appendChild(lat);
    var lng = document.createElement("input");
    lng.name="longitude";
    lng.value=$("#citta[name=longitude]").val() || " ";
    lng.type="hidden";
    form.appendChild(lng);
    var address = document.createElement("input");
    address.name="citta";
    address.value=$("#citta[name=citta]").val() || " " ;
    address.type="hidden";
    form.appendChild(address);
    var game = document.createElement("input");
    game.name="game";
    game.value=id;
    game.type="hidden";
    form.appendChild(game);
    $("#openGame").append(form);
    form.submit();
```

and add an element to the html page like

```
<div id='openGame'></div>
```